# Обработка результата програмы

Tags: java, android

Давно хотел написать программу, которая бы работала с результатами других программ. В данном примере, у меня есть на смартфоне сканер штрих-кода, он сканирует штрих-код, и в конце просто выдает окно с номером штрих-кода, так вот, можно ли написать программу чтоб она после сканирования, брала код и записывала его в файл?

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Я бы сделал так:

Получение кода осуществляется с помощью appuim, находим элемент записываем в переменную,
запись кода в файл с помощью стандартной класса File.